# Iterate on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a component in React where you could iterate +1 or -1 on click. Please look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z3cuLys/) and tell me where I am missing the point.
Many thanks for all possible help.

Looking forward,

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {clickCount: 0};
    console.log(this.state)
  } 

  handleClickInc(){
    this.setState({count:this.state.clickCount + 1})
    }

  handleClickDec(){
     this.setState({count:this.state.clickCount - 1})
  }

 render(){
    return 
    <div>
        <div>
        {this.props.clickCount}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickInc}>{"+"}</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickDec}>{"-"}</button>
      </div>
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);`
```

html part

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: this.setState({**clickCount**:this.state.clickCount - 1})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems were:

1) your `return` function was not wrapped in parens, causing a syntax error.

2) your click handlers were not bound to `this` (i.e. you needed to call `this.handleClickInc.bind(this)` or use fat arrow syntax as mentioned above.

3) As mentioned, you were updating the state of `count` but you meant to update `clickCount`.

Here is a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/6z3cuLys/5/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could be missing `.bind()` on there. Without it, `this` has the wrong context as it fires the function.

try

```
    <button onClick={this.handleClickInc.bind(this)}>{"+"}</button>
    <button onClick={this.handleClickDec.bind(this)}>{"-"}</button>
```

or, fat arrow functions generally do this work for you

```
    <button onClick={() => this.handleClickInc()}>{"+"}</button>
    <button onClick={() => this.handleClickDec()}>{"-"}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all all render elements must have return right? So your return is missing the () wrapping the div.

Second, to use state in a function you have to bind the function. I use to put the statement inside the constructor.

You can put like this:

```
this.handleClickInc = this.handleClickInc.bind(this);
```

Make this for the other function and it will work.